# RxJS + Angular - immediate and delayed subscription behaves differently

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Let's say I don't know if my observable introduces any delay (f.e. if it makes any http call).

```
observable.subscribe( x => console.log('inner'))
console.log('outer')
```

In such example I have no way to determine which part of code will be executed first - `inner` or `outer`. This gets especially tricky, when using f.e. http call with `shareReplay` - first subscriber will be delayed, further subscribers will receive data immediately:

https://playcode.io/1027001

---

**Is there any recommended way to handle every observable in a deterministic way?**

My particular problem appears with subscriptions in Angular's ngOnInit. If an unknown observable does not introduce a delay, a subscription changing template's variable will throw `"changed after it was checked"`

The only solution that I've came upon is to use `.pipe(delay(0))` before every subscription, but it's quite dirty and difficult to remember.

**EDIT** results:
In typical cases such non-determinism should never be a problem. Each subscription should clearly be connected with corresponding data, f.e. when one subscription depends on other.
In Angular only `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is problematic. `OnInit` and `OnChanges` will not throw `changed after it was checked` in described case.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bexce4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In the first code, it shouldn't matter. If you need a strict ordering, one should depend on the other (if "outer" should always be printed after, it should be made a part of the Observable pipeline to make that explicit).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think you're right, for now I can't think of an real life example, outside ngOnInit, that would be problematic.

Comment: You could also subscribe in the constructor. If the Observable is synchronous, the value will be set before `ngOnInit`. Or use an `async`-pipe where apllicable.

Comment: @churill Unluckily `@Inputs` are not available in constructor and they are necessary for my case.

Comment: @JoshThunar So the inputs are only consumed once in `ngOnInit` when you setup alle the Observables? What if the input changes? I usually initialize all observables in ctor and have subjects to react to changes in inputs. Maybe you could post an example with the angular code, on StackBlitz maybe?

Comment: @churill Thank you, your comment gave me a second perspective. You are right, this should never be problematic, except for the `AfterViewInit`. But this is quite specific case. In normal work we can use `OnInit` and `OnChanges` and they will work just fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bexce4?file=src/app/app.component.ts